# Как отслеживать что пользователь находится на странице и смотрит трансляцию?

Tags: javascript

У меня проект, где клиент должен смотреть обучающуюся трансляцию, а после этого пройти тестирование.
Трансляция это обычный iFrame из Youtube или другого сервиса. Сам проект на JS и отдельно существует сервер (куда отправляются данные через API).

Какие есть идеи для реализации проверки активности, что клиент смотрит трансляцию?

Comment: А какие есть ещё варианты кроме отслеживания курсора мышки?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Мышь не вариант, так как пользователь смотрит трансляцию и вряд ли двигает мышкой...

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать следующее:

- При запуске видео ставьте переменную `isWatching` на `true`
- Поставьте `blur` ивент на `window` (он происходит когда пользователь покидает страницу)
- Ивент `focus` который происходит, когда пользователь фокусируется на странице (также на объекте `window`)

Изменяйте значение переменной взависимости от того, находится ли пользователь на странице, либо же покинул её. Также можете воспроизводить инные манипуляции при помощи данных ивентов.